# logging.debug( ) is running code when the level is set to WARNING. (PYTHON)

Tags: python

So I was trying to automate the Mid term factorization process. My program is working except the logger.debug(condSecond(5, '+', 6)) at line 38 is executing the function condSecond() even when I've set the level to "WARNING".
How can I avoid executing the function. (BTW I know I could just delete that line. I don't wanna do that.)

and sorry idk how to add line number here.

```
import math
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('Debugger')
logging.basicConfig(level="WARNING")

def getFactors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
           #factors.append(n // i)    not required for this program.
    return factors


logger.debug(getFactors(174))


def condSecond(x, o, n): # o -> operator ; x -> coefficient of variable with degree 1; n -> product of constant and coefficient of squared variable.
    x = int(x)
    n = int(n)
    if o == '+':
        for i in getFactors(n):
            if i + n/i == x:
                print(f"{i}x + {n//i}x")
                return
        print('not solvable (check the arguments you passed)')

    elif o == '-':
        for i in getFactors(n):
            if i - n/i == x:
                print(f"{i}x - {n//i}x")
                return
            elif i- n/i == -x:
                print(f"{n//i}x - {i}x")
                return
        print('not solvable (check the arguments you passed)')

logger.debug(condSecond(5, '+', 6))

def midTermFactorization(a, b, o, c): # b -> coefficient of variable having degree 1 ; c -> constant ; a -> coefficient of squared variable
    n = int(a) * int(c)
    condSecond(b, o, n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp = input('coefficient of squared variable: ')
    inp2 = input('coefficient of variable: ')
    inp3 = input('operator before the constant: ')
    inp4 = input('constant: ')
    midTermFactorization(inp, inp2, inp3, inp4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The logger flag is just here to tell the logger which message shall be filtered out and which shall be saved/printed. So the function used as argument to logger.debug is always executed. It results is printed /logged depending on the logger level.

What you can do is test the level passed to the logger (eg here warning) to decide if you want to call the logger.debug or not.

Comment: So there is no way to completely stop the logger.debug() from executing?